# magento2 smtp send mail

Tags: magento2.3

I have a problem, i composered smtp in github and i want create send mail

I have file app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template   id="helloworld_options_helloworld_group_email_template_invalid" 
            label="Email template invalid" 
            file="email/helloworld_email_template_invalid.html" 
            type="html" 
            module="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" 
            area="frontend"
/>
</config>
```

I have file app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/email/helloworld_emai_template_invalid.html

```
<!--@subject Email Subject @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url = \"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image",
"htmlescape var=$recipient_name":"Recipient Name",
"htmlescape var=$recipient_email":"Recipient Email"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body {background: #F6F6F6; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body, td {
color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
@-->

<body>
<div>
    <table cellspcing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <!-- [header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0">
                    <!-- [middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 22px; margin:0 0 11px 0">Dear {{var email}},</h1>
                            This is the email that send from our magento system
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Congratulation you signup complete</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>You has buy a ticket {{var name}} with type is {{var typeId}}</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>A ticket {{var typeId}} has changes about status: {{var statusId}} </p>        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{store url="ticket/frontend/manageaticket/"}}uniqueCode/{{var uniqueCode}}"><span>View Detail Ticket</span></a>
                            <br/>
                            view: {{store url="ticket/frontend/manageaticket/"}}uniqueCode/{{var uniqueCode}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align: center;">
                            <center>
                                <p style="font-size:12px; margin:0">
                                    Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong>
                                </p>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

I have file app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Helper/Email.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Email extends AbstractHelper {
const EMAIL_APPROVAL_INVALID = 'helloworld_options/helloworld_group/email_template_invalid';
/**
 * @var StateInterface
 */
protected $_inlineTranslation;

/**
 * @var TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var CustomerSession
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $_url;

protected $_template;

protected $_messageManager;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CustomerSession $customerSession,
    UrlInterface $url
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->_url = $url;
}

protected function getConfigValue($path, $storeId) {
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );
}

protected function getTemplateId($xmlPath) {
    return $this->getConfigValue($xmlPath, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
}

protected function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables, $senderInfo, $receiverInfo) {
    $template = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->_template)
        ->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ]
        )
        ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
        ->setFrom($senderInfo)
        ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'], $receiverInfo['name'])
        ->setReplyTo($senderInfo['email'], $senderInfo['name']);

    return $this;
}

public function sendEmail($template, $emailTemplateVariables){
    $result = [
        'error' => false
    ];
    $this->_template = $this->getTemplateId($template);

    $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();

    $senderInfo = [
        'email' => $this->getConfigValue( 'trans_email/ident_custom2/email', $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()),
        'name' => $this->getConfigValue( 'trans_email/ident_general/name', $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
    ];

    $receiverInfo = [
        'email' => $emailTemplateVariables['email'],
        'name' => $emailTemplateVariables['name']
    ];

    $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables, $senderInfo, $receiverInfo);

    try {
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $result = [
            'error' => false,
            'message' => 'Email is sent successfully'
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result = [
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
    }

    $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();

    return $result;
}

public function sendEmailHelloWorldInvalid($emailTempVariables) {
    $this->sendEmail(self::EMAIL_APPROVAL_INVALID, $emailTempVariables);
}
}
```

And i have file app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/SendMail.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Email;

    class SendMail implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $helperEmail;

    public function __construct(
        Email $helperEmail
    ) {
        $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $data['name'] = 'Boll';
        $data['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';

        return $this->helperEmail->sendEmailHelloWorldInvalid($data);
    }
    }
```

I don't know which file I am missing. Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your controller `SendMail.php`.  you implement `ObserverInterface` in that controller correct is controller always extend `Magento\Backend\App\Action`.

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Email;

class SendMail extends Action
{
    private $helperEmail;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Email $helperEmail
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data['name'] = 'Boll';
        $data['email'] = 'khazjx123@gmail.com';
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        try {
            $this->helperEmail->sendEmailHelloWorldInvalid($data);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You send mail success.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('mageplaza_helloworld/post/index');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the record.'));
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('mageplaza_helloworld/post/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: it working. thank you devidas

Comment: great ...! Welcome @HưngNguyễn